# Negative lookbehind: How can I stop matches when the suffix is repeated?

Tags: java, regex, negative-lookbehind

I have some `suffix` that I want to match when some `prefix` is absent. However, the `suffix` might be repeated.

**Some examples:**

```
 1. prefixsuffix - should not match
 2. prefixsuffixsuffix - should not match
 3. prefixsuffixsuffixsuffix - should not match
 4. suffix - should match
 5. suffixsuffix - should match
 6. suffixsuffixsuffix - should match
```

I have tried this regex: `(?<!prefix)suffix`, which fails on examples 2, 3, since the later `suffix` are matched.

So I tried this regex: `(?<!prefix)(suffix)*` hoping it would allow `suffix` to be repeated, but it seems to have the same issue.

So I want a regex which fulfils the above examples.

Answer (score 1):

In your negative lookbehind, alternate with `suffix`, and when matching `suffix` for real, use `+` instead of `*` (because `*` may match *zero* occurences, which is not desirable):

```
(?<!prefix|suffix)(suffix)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/pEoYRA/1

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe we could start with this expression,

```
^(?=(?!prefix)(suffix))\1+$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gkxEAo/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(?=(?!prefix)(suffix))\\1+$";
final String string = "prefixsuffix\n"
     + "prefixsuffixsuffix\n"
     + "prefixsuffixsuffixsuffix\n\n"
     + "suffix\n"
     + "suffixsuffix\n"
     + "suffixsuffixsuffix";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put it, `(?!prefix)suffix` _suffix_ will never equal _prefix_. Therefore, the assertion is always true !

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a word boundary assertion before your lookbehind to make sure you match starting from a word character:

```
\b(?<!prefix)(?:suffix)+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Riz2OT/1)

However looking at your data even `\b(?:suffix)+` may also work for you.

Comment: Your expression is directly equal to `(?<!prefix)\b(?:suffix)+` and since the separation between prefix and suffix is never a word boundary, `(?<!prefix)` will always be true. But, its the wrong answer.